# Jquery targeting a parent div not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button that when clicked I want to fadein another section which is named 'hidden'. I dont think I am targeting it properly working my way up the markup.

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.singleBtn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500);
    $(this).parent('.pt-trigger-container').find('.hidden').fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

I have also created a [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/VVNSF/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.parents()` not `.parent()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.singleBtn').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500);
        $(this).parents('.pt-trigger-container').find('.hidden').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

or you can use `.closest()` as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.singleBtn').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500);
        $(this).closest('.pt-trigger-container').find('.hidden').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

---

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.singleBtn').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500);
        $(this).closest('.pt-trigger-container').next().fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVNSF/10/)**

Comment: thank you for getting back to me, but unfortunately that hasnt worked :(

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: That the div '.hidden' fades in

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many closing divs after your buttons. @Felix's changes will work, I've updated a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VVNSF/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.singleBtn').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500);
        $(this).closest('.pt-trigger-container').find('.hidden').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```